# Unable to run TestCaseSource tests when the type under test overrides ToString

Tags: unit-testing, f#, nunit, fsunit, testcasesource

First, let me present the test setup in F# (using FsUnit on top of NUnit):

```
type SimpleRecord = { A: int; B: int } 
                    override x.ToString() = x.A.ToString()

[<TestFixture>]
type ``Simple Test Cases``() =     
    static member SimpleDataSource =
        [|
            [|{ A = 1; B = 2} ,3|]
        |]

    [<TestCaseSource("SimpleDataSource")>]
    member x.``SimpleTest`` (testData: SimpleRecord * int) =
        let data, expected = testData
        data.A + data.B
        |> should equal expected
```

This test will run and pass as expected.  However, changing the `ToString` override to include a call to `Guid.ToString()` will prevent the test from being run:

```
type SimpleRecord = { A: int; B: int } 
                    override x.ToString() = x.A.ToString() + Guid.NewGuid().ToString()
```

With the above change, the test still appears in Test Explorer, but it will not be run.  Even right-clicking on it and selecting Run Selected Tests will not execute the test.  No build errors are reported.

I also experimented with using `DateTime.ToString()` instead of `Guid.ToString()`, but that also refuses to run:

```
type SimpleRecord = { A: int; B: int } 
                    override x.ToString() = x.A.ToString() + DateTime.Now.ToString()
```

Why would calling `Guid.ToString()` or `DateTime.ToString()` within the `ToString` override on the type being tested result in the test not running?

Comment: This looks like a test runner issue to me. I can reproduce it with the NUnit Test Adapter for Visual Studio, but if I run the tests with nunit-console.exe, it works fine. It also works fine with TestDriven.Net.

Comment: I guess you're talking about the ReSharper test runner?

Comment: @MarkSeemann You are correct!  I've posted the explanation and solution below.

Comment: @Matthias I'm using Visual Studio 2013 Test Explorer with NUnit Test Adapter.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Charlie Poole provided an explanation of the root cause:

> When tests are run using the NUnit console or gui runners, they are
>   first loaded (discovered) and then executed. When running under the
>   adapter, the tests are loaded twice, once in the discovery phase and
>   again at the beginning of the execution phase. This is a result of the
>   way the VS Test Window works: discovery and execution are run in
>   separate processes created by VS.
>
> This doesn't cause a problem in most cases. The tests are loaded
>   twice, which means the code for creating any test data is run twice.
>   Usually, the same data is generated both times.
>
> However, when using random data, it's known that different data will
>   be generated in each phase. Tests that are shown in the initial
>   discovery seem to disappear while "unknown" tests are run.
>
> In your case, the guid is generated twice. The first one is used as
>   part of the name of the test, consequently, that test disappears in
>   the execution phase.

Here's an example that demonstrates the workaround:

```
type ProblemRecord = { A: int; B: int } 
                     override x.ToString() = Guid.NewGuid().ToString()

[<TestFixture>]
type ``Test Cases``() =     
    // Using TestCaseData and explicitly setting a name will resolve the problem
    member x.SolutionDataSource =
        [
            TestCaseData(({ A = 1; B = 2} : ProblemRecord), 3)
                .SetName("Workaround")
        ]

    // This test case will be run by Test Explorer
    [<TestCaseSource("SolutionDataSource")>]
    member x.``SolutionTest`` (data: ProblemRecord, expected: int) =
        data.A + data.B
        |> should equal expected
```